# UEFI - Linux Mint Boot from USB Doesn't work

Tags: boot, linux-mint, uefi, efi

I'm running Linux Mint (only OS other than in VirtualBox) and wanting to remove it. I've created a **Live USB of Windows 8** using **Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool** - Yes, I know it says Windows 7 but I've been doing research and I am hearing from everywhere that it also works for Windows 8.

- The ISO was loaded on just fine (AFAIK)
- Computer came with Windows 8 pre-installed
- I have **Safe boot** and **Fast boot** disabled in the BIOS Settings
- I have USB as my first boot option
- I have tried both the USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports

Yet, Mint is all that will boot up.

Anybody have a similar issue?

If it helps, the computer is a Toshiba Satellite S855D Laptop with an AMD APU quad-core processor (3 CPU, 1 GPU)

Answer (score 0):

While trying different things, I've got it to work and am now operating on Windows again.

Solution:

**Legacy Boot** inside the BIOS settings should be enabled. I believe the selection will be labeled as **CSM** (as opposed to **EFI**) and in the accompanying description it is referred to as legacy.

Started right up from the USB. Now to tell the others.